# Simple java method using text.io

Tags: java

If somebody could please help me troubleshoot this simple assignment I would be forever thankful! I am very new to Java and cannot understand how to go about debugging this simple code.

I need to:

• Read an external file that has an ice-cream flavor listed on each line

• Count the total number of ice creams

• Count the number of ice creams with the name “strawberry”

• Calculate the percentage of ice creams that are “strawberry”

This is what I have got so far...

```
package icecreamcounter;

import java.io.*; //Import TextIO

public class IcecreamCounter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Open file for reading; if it cannot be opened, end the program
         try {
     TextIO.readFile("icecream.dat");
  }
  catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
     System.out.println("Can't open file \"icecream.dat\" for reading!");
     System.out.println("Please make sure the file is present before");
     System.out.println("running the program.");
     System.exit(1);  // Terminates the program.

     //read the file
     string flavor;
     int strawb; //Total number of strawberry icecreams
     int totalIcecream; // Total number of icecreams
     double percentageStrawb; //Percentage of icecreams which are strawberry

     strawb = 0;
     percentageStrawb = (totalIcecream - strawb)/totalIcecream;

     while (!TextIO.eof()) {  // process one line of data.
         flavor = TextIO.getlnString();  // Get the rest of the line.
         totalIcecream = totalIcecream + 1; // Add one to the count of total icecreams
         return totalIcecream;
         if (flavor.equals("Strawberry") { // If icecream name is strawberry 
             strawb=strawb+1;         //then add one to the count of strawberry
             return strawb;
         }
     }

     System.out.println("Total number of cones is" totalIcecream);
     System.out.println("Total number of strawberry cones is" strawb);
     System.out.println("Percentage of strawberry cones is" percentageStrawb);
  }
}
```

}

The issue might be with the read file part, but it is also giving me errors at the bottom when I try to print the answers. Also, do I have to return the values for example 'totalIcecream' in order to print it out later? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: First thing, close the `catch` after the `System.exit(1)` rather than have the entire program inside it.

Comment: is it mandatory for you to use TextIO?

Comment: Unfortunately yes :( It is for an assignment, specifically asking to use TextIO.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, after the `system.exit(1)`, close up the catch block, because the code after that would never be reached.

Second, in the `println`, it is supposed to be, `"this is some text" + somevariable`

Adding a string variable or number to a string requires a plus sign.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use NIO, for me it works perfect and also is easy to understand, here's my approach using the NIO API of Java (available since Java 1.5)

```
try {
        Path pathToMyTextFile = Paths.get("c:/data/icecream.dat");

        //Here you must use the Charset according to the encoding of your TEXT file (I use ISO_8859_1)
        List<String> linesInFile = Files.readAllLines(pathToMyTextFile, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

        int totalNumberOfIceCreams = linesInFile.size();
        String targetFlavor = "Strawberry";//I would like to handle this in a variable
        int numberOfTargetFlavor = 0;

        for (String iceCreamLine : linesInFile) {
            if (iceCreamLine.equals(targetFlavor)) {
                numberOfTargetFlavor++;
            }
        }

        //Here I calculate the percentage:
        double percentage = (numberOfTargetFlavor * 100) / totalNumberOfIceCreams;

        System.out.println("Total number of Ice Creams: " + totalNumberOfIceCreams);
        System.out.println("Total number of " + targetFlavor + " Ice Creams: " + numberOfTargetFlavor);
        System.out.println("Percentage of Ice Creams that are flavor " + targetFlavor + ": " + percentage + "%");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Control your exception here
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I use a file called "icecream.dat" that was in my c:/data folder. The contents of this file is the following:

```
Strawberry
Chocolate
Strawberry
Orange
Cheese
Strawberry
Raspberry
Apple
Strawberry
```

The output I got is:

```
Total number of Ice Creams: 9
Total number of Strawberry Ice Creams: 4
Percentage of Ice Creams that are flavor Strawberry: 44.0%
```

I know this is not TextIO, but is also a good approach. If it is mandatory for you to make the exercise using TextIO, well, now you have a new approach if you need it in a future.

Regards and Happy Coding :)

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use Text.IO but thanks for that I will definitely try that in the future!